# Dynamic svg favicon?

Tags: javascript, svg, favicon, fabricjs

I have an icon as SVG.
I want to have it in different colors as favicon.

Since there isn't any toDataUrl() for SVG elements I don't see a solution that doesn't involve a server.

Any idea for a client side solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[fabric.js](http://github.com/kangax/fabric.js) supports rendering of SVG elements into `canvas` elements.

Comment: Downvoted. OP asked for a client-side only solution for favicons.

Comment: @JoshH right, so take fabric.js, render the given SVG inside a `canvas` element, then export the image as data URL and use that as the favicon URL.

Comment: Clever. That wasn't clear from the answer before. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 5):

This is not exactly what you asked, but [here's a page](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/favicon/favicon.html) testing the support for svg favicons in browsers.

If the browser supports svg as favicon it's trivial to generate a data url from the svg markup and use that. However, if you wanted a raster image (png, jpg) then yeah, look at the canvas solution. Some people even make [games in the favicon](http://www.p01.org/releases/DEFENDER_of_the_favicon/)...

Comment: "If the browser supports svg as favicon it's trivial to generate a data url from the svg markup and use that" what do you mean?

Comment: @brillout.com probably something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/estelle/SJjJb/

Answer (score 2):

You have an SVG icon and you want to use it as a favicon so you can show it in different colors without hitting the server.

> Any idea for a client side solution?

Firefox 41 [introduced support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/41#SVG) for SVG favicons. Here's an example I tested in Firefox 52 just now:

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="any" href="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512'%3E%3Cpath d='M224 387.814V512L32 320l192-192v126.912C447.375 260.152 437.794 103.016 380.93 0 521.287 151.707 491.48 394.785 224 387.814z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E">
```

Drop it in your page and watch it update as you alter it via script.

**Notes**

- Use the [`sizes` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-link-sizes) with a [value of `any`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#attr-link-sizes-any) to hint to the browser it's a vector icon.
- For browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-svg.
- See [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris) for encoding tips.

Comment: Neat! How about Chrome, Safari & IE?

Comment: Great question! I've Updated the answer to include browser support. Here's the feature request in Chrome, which looks to be getting some attention lately: https://crbug.com/294179